# Stop a function when I click on a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to stop a function when I click on a div `"ego"`. The function displays or hides the `header` depending on the position of the scroll and should only work by default.

Here's my code:

```
$("#ego").click(function(e){
    var $this = $(this);
    if($this.data('clicked', false)){
        hasScrolled();
    }
    e.stopPropagation();
});

var didScroll;
    var lastScrollTop = 0;
    var delta = 5;
    var navbarHeight = $('header').outerHeight();

    $(window).scroll(function(event){
        didScroll = true;
    });

    setInterval(function() {
        if (didScroll) {
            hasScrolled();
            didScroll = false;
        }
    }, 250);

    function hasScrolled() {
        var st = $(this).scrollTop();

        // Make sure they scroll more than delta
        if(Math.abs(lastScrollTop - st) <= delta)
            return;

        // If they scrolled down and are past the navbar, add class .nav-up.
        // This is necessary so you never see what is "behind" the navbar.
        if (st > lastScrollTop && st > navbarHeight){
            // Scroll Down
            $('header').animate({top:"-178px"}, 200, 'easeOutCubic');
        } else {
            // Scroll Up
            if(st + $(window).height() < $(document).height()) {
             $('header').animate({top:"0px"}, 200, 'easeOutCubic');
            }
        }

        lastScrollTop = st;
    }
```

Here's the fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/antoniobarcos/wL2vuv4h/2/

Any idea?

Comment: i don't see where you set your data-clicked in ego. maybe you should use: `$('#ego').click(function(e){e.preventDefault();}` do you have a fiddle for this?

Comment: within your function use an if(clicked) return false; - Switch the clicked boolean to true when clicked

Comment: @DomlThe-Bread Here's the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/antoniobarcos/wL2vuv4h/2/ Any suggestion? I've added a stopPropagation() but the function still running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so if i get you right you want to **stop** hiding the navigation bar on top when you click a certain div:

you can achieve this by adding a class on click on the button to your `#ego` like `stopNavigation`. further you have to adjust your `if` clause where you set the `top` position of the header:

```
    $("#ego").click(function(e){
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.toggleClass('stopNavigation');
    });
```

and

```
        if (st > lastScrollTop && st > navbarHeight && !$('#ego').hasClass('stopNavigation')){
            // Scroll Down
            $('header').animate({top:"-178px"}, 200);
        }
```

i updated your fiddle for further information! i hope this is what you want to achieve: https://jsfiddle.net/wL2vuv4h/3/

Comment: Thank you so much for your fast answer. That is exactly I wanted.